# .Net SFTP Public/Private Key Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, private-key, public-key

Looking for some insight into how I could implement my own public key authentication method in .Net. I'm using CompleteFTP Server which does handle this type of authentication but requires manual intervention. I'm extending an API to handle the authentication as part of an automated process

Comment: FTP or SFTP? These are not the same. In any case the answer is "Use a library".

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (as I did exactly this on a project a couple of months ago), would be to shell out to the OS/command line tools to do this.

It's a bit of a pain to parse the output of the tools, but as it's a fairly limited set of results you need to handle, not impossible.